# Visual Studio google search and link click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I can do Google's search. However, to increase my site until you find the page you've found my site, and then I want to click on my site.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim txtsearch As String
    txtsearch = kelime.Text
    txtsearch = "https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=" & txtsearch
    browser.Focus()
    ' From here I can not.



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to write a program which will artificially inflate your PageRank.  I'll save you some time - it's not going to work.  There are programs out there which do seem able to confer improvements to PageRank, but it's a cat and mouse game between their developers and Google to close the loopholes and ensure that the programs do not work.

If I'm wrong, and you are attempting to do the above for legitimate reasons, then I suggest you scrape the browser source for the URL of your URL once the results page has loaded (you need to handle the loaded event), and if it's found simulate a mouseclick over it.  Otherwise keep incrementing the page attribute in the search URL.